# Why is incorrect URL used for glassfish's security-all jar from Maven repo?

Tags: glassfish, sbt

I added the following to `build.sbt` (doing programmatic login with embedded GlassFish for unit tests):

```
libraryDependencies += "org.glassfish.main.security" % "security-all" % "4.0"
```

However sbt seems to try to fetch the wrong URL.  It tries to get (note the additional `glassfish-` in the extension):

```
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/main/security/security-ee/4.0/security-ee-4.0.glassfish-jar
```

But the actual jar file is at:

```
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/main/security/security-ee/4.0/security-ee-4.0.jar
```

So instead of using `.jar` as the extension it appears to be using `.glassfish-jar` for some reason and am facing the following `download failed` errors:

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.glassfish.main.security#security;4.0!security.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.admin#config-api;4.0!config-api.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.common#common-util;4.0!common-util.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.common#glassfish-api;4.0!glassfish-api.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.common#scattered-archive-api;4.0!scattered-archive-api.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.security#ssl-impl;4.0!ssl-impl.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.common#internal-api;4.0!internal-api.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.deployment#deployment-common;4.0!deployment-common.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.security#security-ee;4.0!security-ee.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.common#glassfish-ee-api;4.0!glassfish-ee-api.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.deployment#dol;4.0!dol.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.common#annotation-framework;4.0!annotation-framework.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.security#jaspic.provider.framework;4.0!jaspic.provider.framework.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.ejb#ejb-internal-api;4.0!ejb-internal-api.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.connectors#connectors-internal-api;4.0!connectors-internal-api.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.transaction#transaction-internal-api;4.0!transaction-internal-api.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.admin#admin-util;4.0!admin-util.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.security#security-services;4.0!security-services.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.resources#resources-connector;4.0!resources-connector.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.resourcebase.resources#nucleus-resources;4.0!nucleus-resources.glassfish-jar
[error] download failed: org.glassfish.main.security#inmemory.jacc.provider;4.0!inmemory.jacc.provider.glassfish-jar
```

I have no idea why or even where to look. I would think it would be something with the pom file, but Netbeans (probably the Maven embedded in Netbeans) did not have any trouble with the same pom.

Also, all the "transitive" jars end up have the wrong URL as well, so they all fail.

I worked around it with this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.glassfish.main.security" % "security-ee" % "4.0"  from "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/main/security/security-ee/4.0/security-ee-4.0.jar" intransitive()
```

but I would rather not have to do that *hoping* there is a way to do this properly.  My searches for a real solution to this came up empty. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the behaviour is that the module defines the packaging `glassfish-jar` for some of the transitive dependencies - see [inmemory.jacc.provider-4.0.pom](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/main/security/inmemory.jacc.provider/4.0/inmemory.jacc.provider-4.0.pom) and [security-4.0.pom](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/main/security/security/4.0/security-4.0.pom):

```
<packaging>glassfish-jar</packaging>
```

Run `sbt update` in the project and open `target/resolution-cache/reports/default-glassfish-security_2.10-compile.xml` for the resolution report for the `Compile` (default) configuration.

Use [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) to visualize your project's dependencies.

Comment: I did these steps, but it was unclear to me what to do next. What do I do about the glassfish-jar packaging?

Comment: I would find the dependency that drags the others with the `glassfish-jar` packaging and [exclude it](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#exclude-transitive-dependencies).